# copy record some tables with dependence

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

```
CREATE TABLE a (
    a_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    a_value varchar(255)
);
CREATE TABLE b (
    b_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    b_value varchar(255),
    a_id INT REFERENCES a(a_id) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (a_id, b_value)
);
CREATE TABLE c (
    c_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    c_value varchar(255),
    b_id INT REFERENCES b(b_id) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (b_id, c_value)
);

INSERT INTO a (a_value) VALUES ('a1'),('a2'),('a3');
INSERT INTO b (a_id, b_value) VALUES (1, 'b01'),(1, 'b02'),(2, 'b01'),(2, 'bbb'),(3, 'b3');
INSERT INTO c (b_id, c_value) VALUES (1, 'c1'),(1, 'c2'),(1, 'c3'),(2, 'c1'),(2, 'c2'),(2, 'c3'),(4, 'c2');
```

How can I copy an entry (eg a_id = 1) in the main table with a different value, but with the same dependences entries?

As manual

```
INSERT INTO a (a_value) SELECT 'copy_' || a_value FROM a RETURNING a_id;
--give a_id = 4;
INSERT INTO b (a_id, b_value) SELECT 4, b_value FROM b WHERE b.a_id = 1 RETURNING b_id;
--give b_id = 6 and 7
INSERT INTO c (b_id, c_value) SELECT 6, c_value FROM c WHERE c.b_id = 1;
INSERT INTO c (b_id, c_value) SELECT 7, c_value FROM c WHERE c.b_id = 2;
```

with two tables work this:

```
WITH
a_ AS (
INSERT INTO a (a_value) SELECT 'copy_'||(SELECT COUNT(a_id) FROM a WHERE a_value LIKE 'copy_%')||'_'||a_value FROM a WHERE a_id = 1 RETURNING a_id
)
INSERT INTO b (a_id, b_value) 
    SELECT a_.a_id, b_value FROM a_, b WHERE b.a_id = 1 RETURNING b_id
```

but how copy records in table C? if there will be four tables?

before

```
a_id | a_value
--------------
1    |  a1
2    |  a2
3    |  a3
```

b

```
b_id| a_id| b_value
--------------
1   |  1  |  b01
2   |  1  |  b02
3   |  2  |  b01
4   |  2  |  bbb
5   |  3  |  b3
```

c

```
c_id| b_id| c_value
--------------
1  |  1  |  c1
2  |  1  |  c2
3  |  1  |  c3
4  |  2  |  c1
5  |  2  |  c2
6  |  2  |  c3
7  |  4  |  c2
```

after

a

```
a_id | a_value
--------------
1    |  a1
2    |  a2
3    |  a3
4    |  copy_a3
```

b

```
b_id| a_id| b_value
--------------
1   |  1  |  b01
2   |  1  |  b02
3   |  2  |  b01
4   |  2  |  bbb
5   |  3  |  b3
6   |  4  |  b01
7   |  4  |  b02
```

c

```
c_id| b_id| c_value
--------------
1  |  1  |  c1
2  |  1  |  c2
3  |  1  |  c3
4  |  2  |  c1
5  |  2  |  c2
6  |  2  |  c3
7  |  4  |  c2
8  |  6  |  c1
9  |  6  |  c2
10 |  6  |  c3
11 |  7  |  c1
12 |  7  |  c2
13 |  7  |  c3
```

Comment: Have You tried `WITH a AS ( INSERT INTO a ...), b AS (INSERT INTO b ...) INSERT INTO c...`?

Comment: In B insert new 2 rows eg 2 rows with a_id = 1:

In C insert 6 rows eg b_id IN (1,2)

Comment: So this results here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a6afe3df568348170f000a3c0b22f6e5
are what you have expected from the select with two tables ?

Comment: Yes, but i want copy records in table C too, which contain links to new entries in table B

Answer (score 0):

I add column in table B

```
 old_b_id INT REFERENCES b(b_id)
```

and make query as

```
WITH
a_ AS (
INSERT INTO a (a_value) SELECT 'copy_'||(SELECT COUNT(a_id) FROM a WHERE a_value LIKE 'copy_%')||'_'||a_value FROM a WHERE a_id = 3 RETURNING a_id
),
new_a AS(
SELECT b_id, a_.a_id FROM b, a_ WHERE b.a_id = 3
)
,b_ AS (
INSERT INTO b (a_id, b_value, old_b_id) SELECT new_a.a_id, b_value, new_a.b_id FROM new_a LEFT JOIN b USING(b_id) RETURNING b_id, old_b_id
)
INSERT INTO c (b_id, c_value) SELECT b_.b_id, c_value FROM c INNER JOIN b_ ON (c.b_id = b_.old_b_id)
```

It's work!